# Keep track of the scores (basketball scorekeeper)

Tags: android

i want to make an basketball scorekeeper app but i don't know how to add 2 or 3 points when i push the 2 points button or 3 points button?

the 1 point button works. this is the code of the button:

```
private int MyCount = 0;

final TextView countTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountL);
final Button pointOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OnePointL);

    pointOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyCount++;
            if (MyCount >-1)
            countTextView1.setText("" + MyCount);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Button pointTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TwoPointL);

pointOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyCount+=2;
        if (MyCount >-1)
        countTextView1.setText("" + MyCount);
    }
});
```

and so on...

Comment: thanks. i was desperate. i tried and tried but i didn't know how to solve it.

thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The line that increases MyCount by 1 is `MyCount++`. If you want to increase the score by 2 or 3 points, you need to increase MyCount by two or three by using the same line multiple times or `MyCount += 2`